# How do I remove the root element of an XML document?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I want to remove the root element from an following xml using Java:

```
<BookRequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://test/books.xsd">
 <Book>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Author>xyz</Author>
 </Book>
</BookRequest>
```

so that I will only have this as the final output:

```
<Book>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Author>xyz</Author>
</Book>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Read the xml File and get the child elements of the Root element and add it to a new xml object and create new file of the new xml object.

Comment: what have you already done. provide some code of what you did to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Have a look at the java document object model, if you are not in a position to use xml to java object such as xstream.jaxb

Comment: I have improved your grammar and spelling on this question, and removed Java from your title as it's not needed (it's a tag). Please keep this in mind for future questions!

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) JAR

```
import java.util.Map;

import cjm.component.cb.map.ToMap;
import cjm.component.cb.xml.ToXML;

public class Convert
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String xml = "<BookRequest xsi:schemaLocation='http://test/books.xsd'><Book><Name>abc</Name><Author>xyz</Author></Book></BookRequest>";

        Map<String, Object> map = new ToMap().convertToMap(xml);

        Map<String, Object> map2 = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("BookRequest");

        StringBuilder xmlResult = new ToXML().convertToXML(map2, true);

        System.out.println(xmlResult);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output

```
 -------- XML Detected -------- 
 -------- Map created Successfully -------- 
 -------- Map Detected -------- 
 -------- XML created Successfully -------- 
<Book><Name>abc</Name><Author>xyz</Author></Book>
```